# In any set of ten consecutive positive integers, there is one that is coprime with each one of the others

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Let $a$ be a postive integer and let $A=\{a,a+1,a+2,\ldots,a+9\}.$ Show that there exists some $i$ such that for any $j\neq i$ we have $(a+i,a+j)=1$

Comment: I note (in response to a few flags) that being coprime to the others and being coprime to the product of the others is the same thing (for typical integers).

Comment: True... sorry @davidlowryduda