# Is there any way to find a row of numbers with many prime factors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

According to the Erdos–Kac theorem, $\sigma=\frac{\omega(n)-\log\log n}{\sqrt{\log\log n}}$ is close to the standard normal distribution, where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors on $n$. We can expect that the $\sigma$ rarely exceed, for example, 5, but it is not that difficult to find such numbers. For example,

- $p_n\#$ has $n$ distinct prime factors, i.e., $\omega(p_n\#)=n$, and $\sigma=5.07$ for $n=13$.
- $2^{1000}-1$ can be divided by $2^2-1, 2^4-1, 2^5-1,2^8-1,\ldots,2^{500}-1$, and $\omega(2^{1000}-1)=34$, $\sigma=10.74$.
- A Fibonacci number $F_{1000}$ can be divided by $F_2, F_4, F_5, F_8, F_{10}, \ldots, F_{500}$, and $\omega=23, \sigma=6.77$.

However, their neighbors does not. For example, $2^n-2=2(2^{n-1}-1)$ have algebraic factors, but $2^n-3$ does not and $2^n$ has only the factor $2$. $F_{2m+1}\pm1, F_{2m+1}\pm2$ can be factorized as follows, but $F_{2m+1}\pm3$ does not seem to have algebraic factors.

- $F_{4n+1}-2=F_{2n-1}\cdot L_{2n+2}$, $F_{4n+3}-2=F_{2n+3}\cdot L_{2n}$
- $F_{4n+1}-1=F_{2n}\cdot L_{2n+1}$, $F_{4n+3}-1=F_{2n+2}\cdot L_{2n+1}$
- $F_{4n+1}+1=F_{2n+1}\cdot L_{2n}$, $F_{4n+3}+1=F_{2n+1}\cdot L_{2n+2}$
- $F_{4n+1}+2=F_{2n+2}\cdot L_{2n-1}$, $F_{4n+3}+2=F_{2n}\cdot L_{2n+3}$

So, is there an easy way or formula to find a succession of numbers such that each has many prime factors, especially more than five in a row?

Comment: That way is fine. I was able to find the numbers I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, thank you for letting me know my suggestion met your requirements. As such, I've written & posted an answer, plus deleted my comment as it's now redundant.

Comment: A related notion that you may find interesting is that of stapled sequences. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3085184/207316

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method to determine an arbitrarily long list of consecutive integers, with each one having at least any specified minimum number of distinct prime factors, is by using the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to solve a set of modular equations with appropriate coprime moduli.

For example, to find some positive integer $k$ (e.g., $k \ge 5$) consecutive integers starting at $n$ with each integer having at least $6$ distinct prime factors, a basic set of equations which could be used is (note $p_i$ is the $i$'th prime)

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
n \equiv 0 & \pmod{2(3)(5)(7)(11)(13)} \\
n \equiv -1 & \pmod{17(19)(23)(29)(31)(37)} \\
& \qquad \qquad \qquad \vdots \\
n \equiv -(k - 1) & \pmod{p_{6k-5}(p_{6k-4})(p_{6k-3})(p_{6k-2})(p_{6k-1})(p_{6k})}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Note, though, there's also a basic optimization which can be used. Since the first equation means $n$ is even, then $n + 2$, $n + 4$, etc., are also all even. Thus, one prime factor of the modulus in each of the $3$'rd, $5$'th, etc., equations can be removed. Considering $3$ also divides $n$ (and thus $n + 3$, $n + 6$, etc.), then the $4$'th, $7$'th, etc., equations can each have a prime factor removed from their moduli. This process can be repeated for additional small prime factors.